# Cantor Lebesgue function

Tags: real-analysis

We know that Cantor Lebesgue function does not satisfy F.T.C

But, we also know that if f is absolutely continuous, then f satisfies F.T.C

I think that since f is absolutely continuous, then f' exists a.e x and f' integrable thus, f satisfies F.T.C

We know Cantor Lebesgue function's derivative =0 a.e x .

Then, Cantor Lebesgue function's derivative is not integrable?

How to prove that ??

Comment: Why do you conclude that $f'$ is not integrable? It's obviously integrable - the point is that $\int_a^b f'(t)\,dt\ne f(b)-f(a)$. (Also you say "Since $f$ is absolutely continuous". It's not.)

Comment: Because i think that if f' exists a.e x and f' integrable then f satisfies F.T.C.

Comment: Then, When satisfies F.T.C??

Comment: You can think that if you want, but it is simply not true that if $f'$ exists ae and is integrable then $f$ satisifies FTC. You have a counterexample right in front of you. When does $f$ satisfy FTC? When $f$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: Why?? if f is absolutely continous, then f' exist a.e x and f' integrable . Is not true?

Comment: Ah... Ok.. then If f is absolutely continuous , then F.T.C satisfies?

Comment: Yes, it's true that if $f$ is absolutely continuous then $f'$ exists ae and $f'$ is integrable. "If P then Q" is not the same as "if Q then P"!

Comment: In Wiki, if f is continuous of the closed interval , then F.T.C satisfies. Then, Does "continuous" mean abs. conti?

Comment: _If_ it says that on wikipedia then wikipedia is wrong. I doubt that it says that. _Where_ do you claim it says that? Link?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus I see Corollary

Comment: The $f$ there is what we've been calling $f'$. The $F$ there is what we've been calling $f$. Yes, if $f'$ is continuous then $f$ is absolutely continuous. This does not contradict anything I've said.

Comment: Converse is true?? if f is absolutely conti, then f' is conti?

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$ You should note that that theorem requires that $f$ be differentiable, not just differetiable ae.

Comment: Then, you mean that Is absolutely conti minimum condition for satisfying F.T.S??

Comment: I just typed an anwwer to one of your questions, and when I was done you'd deleted it an asked another question. I quit.